# jquery mobile googlemaps V3 error "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times"

Tags: html, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I want to move the following two tags from the head section to just before the body closing tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC_ZAfl3FiED8J6PHyC_qLzzUnZVgNzOvg&libraries=geometry,places,weather"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

When I do, when navigating to a second page I get the following error: "You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page etc." If the page is reloaded, i.e. full pb, it loads without error.

This only happens with mobile layouts and jquery.mobile included (desktop layouts are fine).

As said, the error also only happens when the scripts are moved from the head section to the bottom of the page. If left at the top, all is fine.

I searched posts and tried the few things I can think of in this case (reloading, desktop vs mobile, head vs body).

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: and the downvote is why exactly? SO should really make it mandatory to give an explanation when downvoting...

Comment: I had this issue on a Cordova app. Not sure if this is what is happening for you. In the Cordova app I included the URL on a specific page and hit that error. I moved that JS to the index.html page instead. This was happening in my case because the framework I use caches the page so it loaded the script multiple times.

Comment: caching seems like a good culprit; the tag is in the master layout where it needs to stay; any idea what else could be done about it?

Comment: It seems like in your case you will need to (maybe) check a global variable   and add the script using jQuery one time? if (_googleAPILoaded === undefined) { $("body").append( google script source); _googleAPILoaded = true }

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a try and let you know